# How to calculate price using 2 separate functions as additional costs?

Tags: javascript, function, price

I am trying to calculate the total cost of an object by selecting from 2 separate items having variable cost to each item. Each item has its own onclick function to select, show and display the item chosen. I can show the price for the additional cost on the individual item but not the sum across both items. I am not sure where/how to include the code, whether it is inside or outside the function and whether my logic actually performs.

```js
    //And the javascript behind it

    const InitPrice = 20;

    var ChangePatchCost = document.getElementById("BlankPatchId");
     ChangePatchCost.addEventListener('click',function(){
      var YourPatch = document.getElementById("YourPatchId");
      var newCost = YourPatch.getAttribute("AdCost");
      return newCost;
     })

    //Change top to custom top

    function changeapparelSRC(imgs) {
      var expandImgapparel = document.getElementById("BlankImageId");
      expandImgapparel.src = imgs.src;
      expandImgapparel.parentElement.style.display = "block";


      //Display apparel name
      var imgText = document.getElementById("YourDesignId");
      imgText.value = imgs.alt;

      var priceHolder = document.querySelector("#price");
      var ApparelCost = imgs.getAttribute("AdCost");

      var YourPatch = document.getElementById("YourPatchId");
      var PatchCost = ChangePatchCost;
      var newCost = parseInt(InitPrice) + parseInt(ApparelCost) + parseInt(PatchCost);
      priceHolder.textContent = "£" + newCost;
      }

    //Change patch to custom patch

    function changepatchSRC(imgs) {
    var expandImgpatch = document.getElementById("BlankPatchId");
    expandImgpatch.src = imgs.src;
    document.getElementById("BlankPatchId").style.display = "block";

    //Display patch name

    var imgText = document.getElementById("YourPatchId");
    imgText.value = imgs.alt;

    //Adjust price according to patch

    var priceHolder = document.querySelector("#price");
    var PatchCost = imgs.getAttribute("AdCost");
    var YourDesign = document.getElementById("YourPatchId");
    var ApparelCost = YourDesign.getAttribute("AdCost");
    var newCost = parseInt(InitPrice) + parseInt(ApparelCost) + parseInt(PatchCost);
    priceHolder.textContent = "£" + newCost;
    }
```

```html
        <div class="Choosedesign">
          <details>
            <summary class="SelectionHeader"><span class="circleborder"></span><span>Choose your design</span></summary>
            <div class="grid">
              <div class="griditem"><img src="Images/Clothes/plain white.png" alt="Plain white" onclick="changeapparelSRC(this)" AdCost=0></div>
              <div class="griditem"><img src="Images/Clothes/plain black.png" alt="Plain black" onclick="changeapparelSRC(this)" AdCost=0></div>
              <div class="griditem"><img src="Images/Clothes/plain blue.png" alt="Plain blue" onclick="changeapparelSRC(this)" AdCost=0></div>
              <div class="griditem"><img src="Images/Clothes/plain orange.png" alt="Plain orange" onclick="changeapparelSRC(this)" AdCost=0></div>
              <div class="griditem"><img src="Images/Clothes/top1.png" alt="Top 1" onclick="changeapparelSRC(this)" AdCost=5></div>
              <div class="griditem"><img src="Images/Clothes/top2.png" alt="Top 2" onclick="changeapparelSRC(this)" AdCost=5 ></div>
              <div class="griditem"><img src="Images/Clothes/top3.png" alt="Top 3" onclick="changeapparelSRC(this)" AdCost=5></div>
              <div class="griditem"><img src="Images/Clothes/top4.png" alt="Top 4" onclick="changeapparelSRC(this)" AdCost=5></div>
              <div class="griditem"><img src="Images/Clothes/top5.png" alt="Top 5" onclick="changeapparelSRC(this)" AdCost=5></div>
            </div>
          </details>
        </div>

        <div class="Choosepatch">
          <details>
            <summary class="SelectionHeader"><span class="circleborder ">2</span><span>Pick your patch</span></summary>
            <div class="grid">
              <div class="griditem"><img src="Images/Patches/No patch.png" alt="No Patch" onclick="changepatchSRC(this)" AdCost=0></div>
              <div class="griditem"><img src="Images/Patches/patch1.png" alt="Patch 1" onclick="changepatchSRC(this)" AdCost=1></div>
              <div class="griditem"><img src="Images/Patches/patch2.png" alt="Patch 2" onclick="changepatchSRC(this)" AdCost=2></div>
              <div class="griditem"><img src="Images/Patches/patch3.png" alt="Patch 3" onclick="changepatchSRC(this)" AdCost=3></div>
              <div class="griditem"><img src="Images/Patches/patch4.png" alt="Patch 4" onclick="changepatchSRC(this)" AdCost=3></div>
              <div class="griditem"><img src="Images/Patches/patch5.png" alt="Patch 5" onclick="changepatchSRC(this)" AdCost=3></div>
           </div>
          </details>
        </div>

    <div class="CustomDesign">
        <div class="CustomImage">
          <img src="Images/Clothes/plain white.png" alt="Plain white t" id ="BlankImageId" onclick="changeapparelSRC(this)" AdCost=0>
          <img src="Images/Patches/patch1.png" alt="" id ="BlankPatchId" onclick="changepatchSRC(this)" AdCost=0 >
        </div>
        <div class="Customdetails">
          <div class="CustomDetailsInfo">
            <div class="CustomOption">
              <input type="text" name="apparel" readonly value="Your Design"  id="YourDesignId" AdCost=0 required>
            </div>
            <div class="CustomOption">
              <input type="text" name="patch" readonly value="Your Patch" id="YourPatchId" AdCost=0 required>
            </div>
            <div class="CustomOption">
              <input type="text" name="size" readonly value="Your Size" id="YourSizeId" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="price">
            <p id="price"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: can you make a single working snippet?

Comment: @NinaScholz like this?

Comment: @NinaScholz Im not sure whats changed

Comment: now you can click *run code snippet*.

Comment: Aahh. Ok. Any advice to why to logic doesnt work?

Comment: I have tried listing them as global variables in the hope the each function will change the value and therefore pass through the other function, yet this still isnt happening. What is the logic i should proceed with the figure this out?